# how to add padding to left and right to the content of after and before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

i want to add padding to left and right of the value of content property of before, after pseudo element..

html is-

```
<div class="header-contact">
    <p>Mail: info@domain.com</p>
    <p>Tel: xxxxx xxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

and css is-

```
.header-contact p{
     float:right;
     padding-left:10px;
     position:relative;
}
.header-contact p:last-child:after{

     content:"|"; //i want to add padding to its right and left

     position:absolutes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. You need to apply `display:block`or `display:inline-block` property on the pseudo element, for it to render with padding:

```
.header-contact p:last-child:after{
     content:"|"; 
     padding:0 10px;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/slavenko/hud54ebt/)

Comment: thanks it is working.. it is my first question here and i am very pleased for getting my answers within few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```css
.header-contact p{
 float: right;
}
.separator{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-contact">
    <p>Mail: info@domain.com</p>
    <p>Tel: xxxxx xxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/slavenko/hud54ebt/)